# More efficient to have one string, replace and then perform a split or have an array of strings and create a new one changing it?

Tags: java, arrays, performance, replace, split

I am undecided what I should do when it comes to prepare the argument for the `ProcessBuilder.command` method.
The method 1 is definitely faster but I am looking for the best efficiency here.

**Method 1:**

```
String test = "ls | grep $name -option";
test = test.replace("$name",textField.getText());
new ProcessBuilder.command(test.split(" "));
```

**Method 2:**

```
String[] test = { "ls", "|", "grep", "$name", "-option" };
String[] newTest = { test[0], test[1], test[2], textField.getText(), test[4] };
new ProcessBuilder.command(newTest);
```

Comment: I guess that there will be no _significant_ difference in execution speed between both versions.

Comment: `new ProcessBuilder.command(new String[]{ "ls", "|", "grep", textField.getText() });`

Answer (score 0):

The second method will be more efficient in overall performance (because of `replace` method implementation and `split` method call).

But in this case there will be no significant difference in execution time.